# Select from dropdown in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am new to selenium and i am trying to select an option from a drop down. Below is the HTML for the dropdown:

```
 <input type="text" ng-blur="getInventoryStatus()" 
  typeahead-on-select="onDeviceSelect($item)" 
  typeahead="device as device.name for device in deviceList| filter:$viewValue |orderBy:'name':false" 
  ng-model="deviceSearch" placeholder="SKU / Item Name" class="form-control 
  ng-pristine ng-valid" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" 
   aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-00F-1916">
```

The `xpath` for the WebElement is :

```
 /html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input
```

I have tried with almost all the methods which I could find in the internet, but nothing is working out.
I tried to use the `Select` class, wrapped the `WebElement` but it throws an exception of `NoSuchElement`.

I tried to lost all the options in a list but in that case got exception `ui.UnexpectedTagNameException.Element` should have tag `Select` but it has `input`. I need to use `xpath` as the identifier with findelements.

Please help me out in this.

Comment: There is no HTML here.

Comment: I had these problems as well, but can't remember the solution now. Try using javascript `jQuery.click()` for selecting the options.

Comment: Select wont work. Can u please check whether `findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='SKU / Item Name']"))` returns you an element?

Comment: findElement(By.xpath(//.....)) retuens the element as i am able to click it . @VivekSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if the dropdown element is an editable field:

```
driver.findElement("dropdown rlement").sendKeys("your value");
```

Comment: thanks. This is working fine. Sendkeys your required value, the required value is shown in the dropdown. You now just have to click the option from the dropdown. Thanks a lot :)